# About use of additional parameters for UTM tagginng in emails links and making them dynamic

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, analytics

I have enabled WAC and use of additional parameters for UTM tagging in emails. But what I would want to do is use [__AdditionalEmailAttribute3] inside email links so that I can make its value dynamic. I would want its value to be different in each link. So , the UTM tag would be the same for all links except the last attribute which would be different. How can this be achieved . Any help would be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: We use personalization strings in these attributes to pass subscriber id something like this sfmc_id=%%subscriberid%%. How complex is your personalization?

Comment: Its just adding description of the link in each link. It simple one attribute value as text to be entered during email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The __AdditionalEmailAttribute3 is a global parameter, which will be same for all your links. Instead, I will suggest you to update the URL string in **Setup > Data Management > Parameter Manager** by adding `%%linkname%%`, like this:

```
utm_source=SFMC​&utm_medium=Email​&utm_content=%%linkname%%&utm_campaign=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%
```

This will take the content from alias: `<a href="https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/" alias="StackExchange">Hello</a>` showing *StackExchange* in this case.

Keep in mind, that it will not populate in cases where Alias is set programatically, e.g.: `<a href="https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/" alias="%%=v(@myAlias)=%%">Hello</a>`

Comment: Thank you.This worked like a magic for my issue.